# Terraform output variable populates only during the second execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am facing a weird situation while running terraform apply. While running terraform apply for the very first time I get the below error. Populated Terraform output is read in a separate python script so when api_gateway_id is null the python script fails.

> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec): Gathering data from Terraform...
> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec): Traceback (most recent call last):
> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec):   File "/home/ec2-user/bin/lambda-deploy", line 65, in 
> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec):     provide_env('LAMBDA_GATEWAY_ID', 'api_gateway_id')
> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec):   File "/home/ec2-user/bin/lambda-deploy", line 57, in provide_env
> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec):     os.environ[key] = TERRAFORM_OUTPUTS[tf_output]
> module.serverless_projects["api/admin.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment (local-exec): KeyError: 'api_gateway_id'

When I retry 'terraform apply' for the second time the value (api_gateway_id) is getting populated and execution is also successful.

## main.tf

```
   resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "gw" {
      name = "LambdaApiGateway"

      endpoint_configuration {
      types = ["PRIVATE"]
      vpc_endpoint_ids = [aws_vpc_endpoint.gw.id]
      }
      binary_media_types = ["*/*"]
   }

   resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api" {
     rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gw.id
     parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gw.root_resource_id
     path_part   = "api"
   }
```

Not only api_gateway_id, even api_gateway_root, api_gateway_resources are also not getting printed on first time execution. I tried terraform init, terraform refresh before the execution, but no luck.

## output.tf

```
output "api_gateway_id" {
      value = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gw.id
   }

   output "api_gateway_root" {
      value = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gw.root_resource_id
   }

   output "api_gateway_resources" {
     value = jsonencode({
     api = aws_api_gateway_resource.api.id,
   })
   }
```

```
resource "null_resource" "serverless_deployment" {
  triggers = {
  source_version = data.aws_s3_bucket_object.package_object.version_id
  }

 provisioner "local-exec" { 
  command = "lambda-deploy ${var.package_name}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the `null_resource.serverless_deployment`

Comment: You should add that code to the question not in a comment ... it provides relevant information about your error, and from the looks of it you should also add the code for the script `lambda-deploy`

Comment: Printed Output from Terraform however it doesnt print api_gateway_id, etc which I believe might the issue for this failure. Correct me if I am wrong.

│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with module.serverless_projects["api/bookmarks.zip"].null_resource.serverless_deployment,on serverless_project/deployment.tf line 6, in resource "null_resource" "serverless_deployment":6:   provisioner "local-exec" {
Error running command 'lambda-deploy api/bookmarks.zip': exit status 1. Output: Gathering data from Terraform...
{"account": {"sensitive": false, "type": "string", "value": XXX"),

Comment: Does your serverless deploy rely on the API gateway In someway. You might have a race condition where the api gateway and serverless deployment resource are running in parallel so  the serverless deployment fails cause the API gateway is not there. When you run it the next time api gateway may already be created. Try putting a `depends_on`  meta argument on the serverless deploy and make it depend on api gateway this will ensure it never runs until after API gateway is created

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle, yes I will try using depends_on but api_gateway_id is used in a different directory, api_gateway (directory) -> gateway.tf (api_gateway_id) and serverless_deployment is used in a different tf dir/file (serverless_deployment (directoy) -> deployment.tf (null_resource.serverless_deployment)

Comment: @Marc you must provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  ... it is very difficult to paint a complete picture of your code structure with as little code as you provided

Answer (score 0):

Terraform only finalizes the updated state snapshot after the apply phase is complete, so it isn't reliable to try to access the state from actions taken during that apply phase.

Instead I would recommend passing the needed values directly to the external program you are running, either using command line arguments or using environment variables set only for that process.

For example:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" { 
    command = "lambda-deploy ${var.package_name}"
    environment = {
      LAMBDA_GATEWAY_ID = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gw.id
    }
  }
```

In the above I used an environment variable name that I saw mentioned in the stack trace your program produced, though you can use any environment variable names you wish and then access them in whatever is the normal way to do so inside the programming language you're using to implement this program. For a Python program, you will no longer need to assign them *into* `os.environ`, because they should already be available there.